# Rails server (Thin)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm running the Thin app server with:

```
rails server
```

After about ten minutes, when I make an API request, the server kind of doesn't reply and spits out these messages instead:

```
Started GET "/users.json?tag=1" for 192.168.0.12 at 2015-02-25 15:05:12 -0500
source=rack-timeout id=7c943asf1 timeout=30000ms service=1005ms state=active
source=rack-timeout id=7c943sdf2 timeout=30000ms service=1005ms state=active
source=rack-timeout id=7c943sdf3 timeout=30000ms service=1005ms state=active
source=rack-timeout id=d8cbc0536fe timeout=30000ms service=30004ms state=timed_out
```

Why is it doing this and how do I fix it? Only way is to restart the server, which take a good ten seconds for me.